# Set div height auto and scroll can be used

Tags: html

```
<div style='width: 240px; height:530px; overflow:scroll;'>
<table>
bla.. bla..
</table>
</div>
```

Dear all, I want to set this div height automatically, but when I change this into height:auto; the data in table cannot be scroll.

Anyone have a suggestions ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style='width: 240px; min-height:530px; overflow:scroll;'>
<table>
bla.. bla..
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use set **min-height** and **max-height**, so if it exceeds the max-height the scroll will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style='width: 240px; height:530px; overflow-y: auto;'>

<table>
bla.. bla..

</table>

</div>
```

We can use other option **overflow: auto;** if we want both scroll bar X And Y